# How to save file from vi editor to a text file

Tags: batch-file, putty

I am trying to execute commands in a text file in a sequence from putty through the following command.

```
putty.exe -ssh domain -l loginname "myProfile" -pw password -m D:\test\myremotecommands.txt
```

in which one of the commands should open the file and save file to some other text file as mentioned below

```
vi test.txt  
:wq demo.txt
```

but when i am trying to execute it is opening the file and cannot able to close it.
Can i know the command which will be closing the file(by changing the mode of `vi` editor).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Are you intending to edit the existing file before saving it into another file using vi editor?